# Insert with a stored procedure and return an output parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to insert values in an Entity database and return true if everything is OK. I tested my stored procedure and it is working fine but when I try to call it from the code I am getting the following error:

> No mapping exists from object type System.Collections.Generic.List`1

My question is: am I calling it properly?

```
using (Entities ent = new Entities())
{
    List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
    parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Parameter1", "Parameter1"));
    parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Parameter2", "Parameter2"));

    SqlParameter outputParameter = new SqlParameter();
    outputParameter.ParameterName = "@Confirm";
    outputParameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit;
    outputParameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

    parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Confirm", outputParameter));

    ent.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec TestProc @Parameter1, @Parameter2", parameters);

    bool success = Convert.ToBoolean(outputParameter.Value);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by an *Entity database*? **Entity Framework** is a **data access** library - **NOT** a database. You don't have an "Entity Framework" database and it doesn't contain any stored procedures - you might have a MySQL, a PostgreSQL, a SQL Server, or an Oracle database which might contain a stored procedure - and you use EF to access that database .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExecuteSqlCommand takes an object[] not a List, so pass parameters.ToArray().

Also don't indicate success or failure with an output parameter.  Just throw an error from the stored procedure if something goes wrong.

And change

```
                SqlParameter outputParameter = new SqlParameter();
                outputParameter.ParameterName = "@Confirm";
                outputParameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit;
                outputParameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

                parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Confirm", outputParameter));
```

to

```
                SqlParameter outputParameter = new SqlParameter();
                outputParameter.ParameterName = "@Confirm";
                outputParameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit;
                outputParameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

                parameters.Add( outputParameter );
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed to parameters.ToArray(). but I still got this error:"No mapping exists from object type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter to a known managed provider native type."

Comment: Updated answer.